# How to fix the holes in this console rotation animation

Tags: c, math, rotation, geometry

I have a square rotating in the console, but I get some holes. How can I fill it correctly?

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <math.h>

void moveTo (int x, int y)
{
    COORD coord = { x, y };
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
}

double round (double number)
{
    return number < 0.0 ? ceil(number - 0.5) : floor(number + 0.5);
}

double deg2rad (double a)
{
    double pi = 3.14159265358979323846;
    return a * pi / 180.0;
}

int main ()
{
    int w = 8;
    int h = 8;
    int cx = 20;
    int cy = 10;

    double a = 0;

    while (1)
    {
        system("cls");

        for (int y = 0; y < h; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < w; x++)
            {
                double xx = x - 4;
                double yy = y - 4;
                double fx = xx * cos(a) - yy * sin(a);
                double fy = xx * sin(a) + yy * cos(a);

                int ix = cx + round(fx);
                int iy = cy + round(fy);

                moveTo(ix, iy);
                printf("X");
            }
        }

        a += deg2rad(15.0);
        Sleep(100);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tell me why down vote, please.

Comment: `system("cls")` is bad practice, consider using this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682022%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Not an actual answer*

Aparently your code will always print the same number of `X` in the screen, even though this might not be always the case.

I think you shouldn't be recalculating the positions of each predefined`X` but instead calculate the geometry of the lines around the square and fill the space between with `X`s, as many as necessary until it hit the opposite border or something.

An alternative solution could be doubling the "density" of your square:

```
int w = 8*2;
int h = 8*2;
int cx = 20*2;
int cy = 10*2;
...
moveTo(ix/2, iy/2);
```

This should double print some dots, but should also fill gaps.